# dovecot Error: No relay host configured for submission proxy (submission_relay_host is unset) after upgrade to version >= 2.3.0

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, dovecot

I find this occurs because of a new feature of dovecot in versions >= 2.3.0 So all I have to do is add "submission" to protocols I lmtpd.protocol and pop3d.protocol in /usr/share/dovecot/protocols.d I don't know if lmtpd.protocol is the right file to add "submission" to protocols
Next I'm supposed to "configure the relay MTA server." In /etc/postfix/main.cf `relayhost = [mail.isp.example]:587` What should I put here, the machine I'm configuring is already my mail server itself What am I supposed to proxy to?

Comment: Sounds like you have partial configuration for a feature you did not use before. Are you certain you want to start using the *submission proxy* feature at all? If you do not have a use case for that, *not* configuring the related settings is fine, too.

Comment: I'm clueless whether or not I should use submission It seemed like the accepted new way to replace previously used protocols by adding this proxy layer which is going to take care of certain things automatically and avoids the redundant copying to sent folder also I don't know why  it doesn't work However the error is permission denied for the cert file